# Обновления в линукс

Tags: linux, bash, update, apt, dnf

Подскажите,в процессе пользования различными дистрибутивами Linux время от времени(а в некоторых дистрибутивах чуть ли не каждый день) появляются различные обновления. Насколько мне известно обновления в линуксе можно разделить на проверенные обновления(т.е те которые точно работают и не сломают систему) и непроверенные. Вопрос в том как понять из предлагаемого списка обновлений какике из них стабильные и их точно можно установить не боясь сломать систему ?
P.S. На данный момент пользуюсь менеджером пакетов dnf.

Comment: Всё это должно быть описано в документации вашего дистрибутива

Comment: Речь идёт об обновлении любых пакетов или ядра? У ядра [явно прописано](https://www.kernel.org/), какие релизы стабильные, какие LTS. Но в любом случае обновление не даёт стопроцентной гарантии, что ничего не поломается. Тем более нет никакой гарантии у неофициальных пакетов. В большинстве лицензий указано что-то типа *THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND*.

Comment: вот например мне прищли такие оюновления, как понять какие из них стабильные или нет ? Может среди них есть обязательные к установке?    вот например что предлагается установить kexec-tools                 x86_64    2.0.25-1.fc36           updates    481 k

Comment: обычному пользователю обычно нужно остерегаться трёх вещей(обновлений): загрузчика(grub), ядра, видео(драйвера/сервера[xorg|wayland]), всё это при неудачном обновлении может погрузить пользователя в темную и непроглядную консоль. Обычно это конечно решается довольно просто, но подростковая травма может остаться надолго.

Answer (score 1):

1. в домашнем варианте допустимо не обновляться, в промышленном, как правило, тоже, что связано с конкретными требованиями устанавливаемого ПО на конкретные системы.
2. также при эксплуатации древнего ПО бывает уже просто критично обновлять, потому как не будет работать (напр., вызов библиотечной функции).
3. суть обновлений: обновить по безопасности (для конкретных дыр конкретного ПО), обновить свежие пакеты, обновить дистрибутив (обычно при смене ядра)
4. "проверенных" обновлений нет (возможно вы подумали о недоверенных репозиториях), слишком много взаимосвязей и проверить эти все вещи невозможно. и обычно ждут до недели-месяца после обновлений о возникших и возникающих критичных обновлениях (а за это время и другие обновления выходят). так что риск есть всегда и это риск применения загрузочного диска для либо обновления системы, либо полной переустановки.
5. большой риск использовать несколько репозиториев, поставляющих одни и те же продукты либо библиотеки, что практикуется практически во всех системах, тут конфликты возникают довольно и намного часто. при обновлении обычно конфликты решаются, но это решение человека.
6. по личной статистике раз в 2-3 года "попадаешь", то есть обновляться можно. например, один раз в полгода-год.

не обновляйтеь пока работает :)

Comment: все обновления постовляемые хорошим дистрибутивом проверенные. если обновляться регулярно, то ничего не слетает.

Answer (score 1):

Ещё третий вид - обновления безопасности.

Типы обновлений лежат в разных репозиториях.

Непроверенные надо включать вручную.

Answer (score 1):

по дефолту в дистре стабильные обновы обычно идут, тестовые репы нужно дополнительно включать, в релизных дистрах наверно могут проблемы вылезти при обновлении версии дистра до более новой